# Is there a tool to test mobile push notifications, without having actual mobile app?

Tags: python, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, pusher

I'm implementing Python backend for pusher notifications and would like to test them before deploying for mobile team to start using the services. Is there a way to test them, without having mobile apps?

If I can simulate mobile app from code (Python) and write tests that way, that would be perfect.

If there is a tool like Postman, or something like that, that would work too.

BTW, I'm trying to use [Pusher Beams](https://pusher.com/beams). The mobile team would use React Native, if that's relevant. The messages would be FCM/APN.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test push notifications in a simulator

you need to real device and **deviceToken** using deviceToken you have to send notifications on mobile

testing tool

Link:- http://pushtry.com/

select google fcm tester

you can also test notifications from Postman

https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3